# Panda Dataframe Copy Issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy

I wanted to make a copy (an independent one) of a dataframe df by doing df_copy = df.copy().

But when I do df['ColumnA'][0] = 1, the df_copy['ColumnA'][0] is also changed to 1. Can I know why? or How to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: mind providing an example? cant replicate that one..

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely not expected behavior. I would suggest checking your version of pandas, as I can't replicate it on the most recent version. It's possible that you have an older version with a bug because a cursory search was able to find [bug reports](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4202) for this around late 2013.